# Purpose of making @Inject(DOCUMENT) optional?

Tags: javascript, angular

A component I'm looking at ([angular-svg-round-progress](https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar)) contains a service with a constructor that use `DOCUMENT` from `@angular/platform-browser`.

It's imported like this:

```
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

And the constructor injection is annotated like this:

```
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(DOCUMENT) document: any) {
   this.supportsSvg = !!(
   document &&
   document.createElementNS &&
   document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg').createSVGRect
);
```

Since `@angular/core` will always be available (I assume), why did the author of the constructor make the `document` parameter `@Optional`?

Also this is the first time I've seen `@Inject(DOCUMENT)` or `@Inject` used in a constructor.  I'd like to read up more on that if anyone knows where the documentation on that is.

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/angular-dependency-injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find in [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_tokens.ts) that:

> Document might not be available in the Application Context when
>   Application and Rendering Contexts are not the same (e.g. when running
>   the application into a Web Worker).

And you might want to use web worker if you run some heavy computations there.